# How to find genetic connection between two nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph, directed-graph, family-tree

One feature in our current project is to find out relationship of two nodes. One node can be generated by two other nodes together. To put it simple, I take them as a family tree, as below:

```
  A      B
 / \     | 
C   D    E 
|    \   / 
F      G
```

I'm going to write a function to decide if two nodes are genetic connected, for example:

```
is_genetic_connected("D", "F"); // returns true because they have common ancestor: "A"
is_genetic_connected("E", "F"); // returns false
```

I'm not sure if we can apply [LCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor) here, or is there any other good algorithm for such problem?

Comment: If you have tons of nodes and few connections, maybe a sparse distance matrix might help as well.

Comment: Why is the first true and the second false? Is this a digraph? Which node is generated by two other nodes together, and are you sure this is a tree?

Comment: @AmiTavory Yes this is a digraph, sorry I don't know how to draw it by ascii. e.g. C and D's father is A, G's parents are D and E

Comment: Just semantics, by "are_related" makes more sense as a method name than "is_genetic_connected"